# Issue with python and swig version compatibility

Tags: python, c++, swig

I was previously working with python 2.7.9 to wrap some c++ code using swig (version 2.0.12) and everything was working well. I then switched over to python 3.7.3 and have been having issues with running swig like I was before.

This is my error message in my terminal:

```
ImportError: /home/_add_array.so: undefined symbol: PyClass_Type
```

I can imagine two possible solutions:

1. The command line commands I'm making to get swig to generate files need to be changed.
2. I need to update to a newer version of swig.

If it's case 1, what about my previous commands aren't correct:

```
swig -c++ -python add_array.i
g++ -fpic -c add_array_wrap.cxx add_array.h add_array.cpp -I/usr/include/python2.7
g++ -shared add_array_wrap.o add_array.o -o _add_array.so
```

If it's case 2, what version of swig is compatible with python 3.7.3? 
I'm running Ubuntu, in case that's relevant.

Thanks!

Comment: You say "I have been having lots of issues" but you forgot to mention what the issues are.

Comment: Thanks John, I've added my error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is certainly wrong:

```
-I/usr/include/python2.7
```

You need to update that to point to your new Python 3.7 installation.

Comment: Ah, noob mistake. I made the assumption that my 3.7 installation was in the same file path location, but due to the system at work, it was located in a completely different place. 

I changed my second line to: 
g++ -fpic -c add_array_wrap.cxx add_array.h add_array.cpp -I/home/myName/tools/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.7.3-h0371630_0/include/python3.7m/

and now swig is at least generating the proper files correctly.

Thanks John!